# Excel | Index Match |

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I require your assistance on the following:

Lets say we got 3 different groups: (A,B,C)

And we have a few value ranges within each group:

```
(Eg. A has 0 - 100, 101 - 200 while B has 0 - 200, 201 - 400 and C has 0 - 300, 301 - 600.)
```

At the end, for each group that falls under whatever range they have, they will be assigned a final number.
(Eg.

```
[A,95] = 0.5 / [A,101] = 1.0
[B,95] = 1.5 / [B,205] = 3.0
[C,95] = 4.5 / [C,308] = 6.0)
```

Currently i have my index match formula as follows:

```
"=INDEX(finalnumber!F2:F29,MATCH(C11&C25,Group!A2:A29&valuerange!D2:D29,0))"
```

I keep getting a #N/A response.

I have also created an array table as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kel18.jpg)

```
Group    Range    Final Number
A        0 - 100      0.50
A        101 - 200    1.00
B        0 - 200      1.50
B        201 - 400    3.00
C        0 - 300      4.50
C        301 - 600    6.00
```

Pls help! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hope this table clarifies!

Comment: What does your actual data look like? Your lookup range should be a single sheet but you have two referenced which is probably part of the problem (Group!A2:A29&valuerange!D2:D29)

Comment: @QHarr, yeah i tried that too. Still returns me a #N/A response.

Trying to get the index/match to read a range of values

Eg. 0 - 100

So the formula would probably read it like:

IF Input is Group "A" and value is "105", the Final number would give an output of "1.00"

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following (you will need to tailor to your layout). I have assumed `A` and `95`, for example, are in separate cells as you concatenate cells in your formula to do your lookup.

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(INDEX(OFFSET(INDEX(C:C,H2),,,I2-H2+1,1),MATCH(VLOOKUP(G2,LEFT(OFFSET(INDEX(B:B,H2),,,I2-H2+1,1),FIND("-",OFFSET(INDEX(B:B,H2),,,I2-H2+1,1))-1)*1,TRUE),LEFT(OFFSET(INDEX(B:B,H2),,,I2-H2+1,1),FIND("-",OFFSET(INDEX(B:B,H2),,,I2-H2+1,1))-1)*1,0))),INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)+1)=F2,G2>=1*LEFT(INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(A:A)+1),FIND("-",INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(A:A)+1))-1),G2<=1*RIGHT(INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(A:A)+1),LEN(INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(A:A)+1)) - FIND("-",INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(A:A)+1)))),INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(A:A)+1),INDEX(OFFSET(INDEX(C:C,H2),,,I2-H2+1,1),MATCH(VLOOKUP(G2,LEFT(OFFSET(INDEX(B:B,H2),,,I2-H2+1,1),FIND("-",OFFSET(INDEX(B:B,H2),,,I2-H2+1,1))-1)*1,TRUE),LEFT(OFFSET(INDEX(B:B,H2),,,I2-H2+1,1),FIND("-",OFFSET(INDEX(B:B,H2),,,I2-H2+1,1))-1)*1,0)))
```

This is entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Formulas in helper cells (to keep overall formula more legible):

`H2` is `=MATCH(F2,A:A,0)` ' finds the first match for the letter e.g. `A`

`I2` is `=MAX(IF(A:A=F2,ROW(A:A)-ROW(INDEX(A:A,1,1))+1))` ' finds the last match for the letter e.g. `A`. This is entered with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Enter</kbd> i.e. an array formula.

---

Data layout

### [image: data]

Example run:

[image: test run]

---

Notes:

You might want to wrap the whole thing in an `IFERROR( formula, "")` to hide any not found error messages.

Comment: Wow, i have no idea what you did but thank you so so very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear why you require four separate worksheets for this operation. For simplicity in demonstrating, I've put your lookup table on the same worksheet as the values to lookup.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(I$2:I$7, (G$2:G$7=LEFT(A2))*(--REPLACE(H$2:H$7, FIND(" - ", H$2:H$7), 9, TEXT(,))<=--MID(A2, 3, 9))*
                                        (--REPLACE(H$2:H$7, 1, FIND(" - ", H$2:H$7)+1, TEXT(,))>=--MID(A2, 3, 9)))
```

[image]

Comment: Neat, I wouldn't have thought of using replace like that. Also the observation that you can use sumproduct because there's only one row that can satisfy all conditions. Curious to know though why you use text(,) instead of "" ?

Comment: It's a habit from writing worksheet formulas in vba coupled with an aversion to using `""""` inside a quoted string.